# the fastest way to get xml and use it in php

Tags: php, xml

until now i was doing `@simplexml_load_file` and on the returned xml i was going with `xpath`

the website got a big traffic and it is taking alot of time for the xml to load.

the host told me to try `get_file_contents` but then i don't know what to do in order to read to returned content as an xml object

they said to try CURL or WGET but for me it is the same like the first one that i'm stuck with

what can i do in order to get xml, as fest as possible from a partners api, and still be able to read it as xml?

Comment: What is taking the time? The pure *downloading* or the *parsing and extracting of information*? And how "long" are we talking here?

Answer (score 2):

**The fastest XML library in PHP is [xmlreader](http://php.net/xmlreader)**. It's pretty obscure (*I think it has very few php users who understand it and are able to use it*) but it is blazing fast because:

> The XMLReader extension is an XML Pull parser. The reader acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way.

Which means that the XML document is not fully preloaded in memory. Only the part that it's currently parsing is loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1):

"The fastest way to get xml" is an oxymoron.
XML is not intended to be fast, it's intended to be compatible.

So, if you need speed - you need another format. And another approach.

1. Store your data **locally** instead of pulling it over the net(!!!) on each user request.
2. Keep it in the database, not XML files

That's all.

Further reading: an article from Stackoveflow founder: [Back to Basics by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: How can you do this with last.fm API? It's **so** huge that you can't possibly sync it all.

Comment: But somewhere we need to use XML, for example fetching and analyzing site feeds! The question is about to choose best method for reading and working with xml files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having trouble getting XML into SimpleXML when your data is in a string. Use [`simplexml_load_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to parse your data from `file_get_contents` or if you get your data remotely (via cURL, etc).

My biggest suggestion is not using `xpath` as it does incur overhead; instead simply refer to the elements in standard object syntax: `$xml->path->value`.

Comment: First, don't optimize before knowing what the problem is.  `simplexml_load_string` can already load URLs.  You just pass that as the file, similar to many other PHP functions.  XPath does impose an overhead, but that can range from tiny to significant.  We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is first you read the file and then

$string = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

It will give you all your xml nodes.
lets suppose you have these nodes

```
 $target_node = $xml->NewsItem->NewsComponent->ContentItem;
            if(isset($target_node))
            {


                foreach($target_node as $child)
                {

                    //isset
                    $story_head = (array)$child->DataContent->CPOnlineFile->CPIndexStoryHead;   
                    if(isset($story_head))
                    {
// go on further by looping and arrowing nodes you will get your desired output... i parse my xml by like this 
}
}
}
```

its just giving you an idea how you can do this...

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2011/07/04/simplexml-vs-xmlwriter-vs-dom/) there is a good blog about **comparing test results for XMLWriter class against SimpleXML and DOM** indicating **XMLWriter class is much faster** when you are working with XML files and have big data rather than other solutions.

XMLReader class can be much similar to XMLWriter class in results.

I hope this helpful.